# How to get multiple names of Active Directory managers?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to get all names that have a word as shown in the image below

I filtered by manager and 2 results appeared, how do I get these two results?

how to get manager 1 and manager 2 by powershell filtering by manager?

[image]

Comment: Those aren't multiple names of the same user, they're multiple accounts matching the text beginning with *managaer*. If you want the accounts which names begin with that, you can use `Get-ADUser`.

Comment: got it, so should i do a simple get-aduser?

Comment: yes, `get-aduser -filter "cn -like 'manager *'"` should get you those results